# Python on Windows 10 - Find window name when mouse hovers

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there a way to get the name of the window that is under the mouse cursor (i.e. the window the mouse cursor is hovering)? The windows is not necessarily the active window.

In my code, I have a function that runs every time the USER presses F2.

I want this function to run, only if the mouse hovers a chrome window.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you provide information about what OS you're using?

Comment: Microsoft Windows 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using pynput and win32 api in python: (works fine for me!)

```
from pynput import mouse
from win32gui import GetWindowText, GetCursorPos, WindowFromPoint

def on_move(x, y):
    print(GetWindowText(WindowFromPoint(GetCursorPos())))   

# Collect events until released
with mouse.Listener(on_move=on_move) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

dont forget to install: `pip install pynput` and `pip install win32gui`